# Ionic 2 SQLite not opening database

Tags: sqlite, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2, and following [this tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/12/use-sqlite-in-ionic-2-instead-of-local-storage/).

My problem is I cannot seem to open the database. I have it deployed to an Android Emulator called KOPLAYER.

**app.ts**

```
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      if (window.cordova) {
        this.createDatabase();
      }
    });
  }
```

and

```
  private createDatabase(): void {
    let db: SQLite = new SQLite();
    db.openDatabase({
      name: "data.db",
      location: "default"
    }).then(() => {
      db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chats (_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, memberIds TEXT, title TEXT, subTitle TEXT, picture TEXT, lastMessageId TEXT, lastMessageCreatedAt DATE)", {}).then((chatData) => {
        console.log("chats TABLE CREATED: ", chatData);
        db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, chatId TEXT, senderId TEXT, ownership TEXT, content TEXT, createdAt DATE, changeDate BOOLEAN, readByReceiver BOOLEAN)", {}).then((messageData) => {
          console.log("messages TABLE CREATED: ", messageData);
        }, (error) => {
          console.error("Unable to execute messages sql", error);
        });

      }, (error) => {
        console.error("Unable to execute chats sql", error);
      });
    }, (error) => {
      console.error("Unable to open database", error);
    });
  }
```

**storageService.ts**

```
public database: SQLite;

constructor() {
    if (window.cordova) {
        this.openDatabase();
    }
}
```

and

```
private openDatabase(): void {
    console.log('openDatabase');
    this.database.openDatabase({ name: "data.db", location: "default" }).then(() => {
        this.refreshChats();
        this.refreshMessages();
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("ERROR: ", error);
    });
}
```

`openDatabase` gets outputted to the console, but the `this.refreshChats();` does not get called. The database creation in `app.ts` looks correct according to the console logs.

> ```
> OPEN database: data.db SQLitePlugin.js:175
> OPEN database: data.db - OK SQLitePlugin.js:179
> chats TABLE CREATED:  Object app.bundle.js:215
> messages TABLE CREATED:  Object app.bundle.js:217
> ```

then

> `openDatabase`

I use `chrome://inspect/#devices` to view the console output. Are there any other tools I can use to view the database running on the emulator?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I forgot the `this.database = new SQLite();`

```
private openDatabase(): void {
    this.database = new SQLite();
    this.database.openDatabase({ name: "data.db", location: "default" }).then(() => {
        this.refreshChats();
        this.refreshMessages();
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("ERROR: ", error);
    });
}
```